# How to manage empty entities and/or entities with no tables using discriminators/inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, hibernate-annotations

I've asked a few times on other sites (and here) but I figure I would try again because I really haven't found an answer. I'm sorta new to hibernate, and I'm scared of posting in hibernate's forums. I'm using mainly JPA annotations with Hibernate 3.6.

I have the following schema:
[image: Schema]

So basically this is a legacy DB. Nomination is the central table, and I have 4 specific types of Nominations:

1. Coworker (which only uses NOMINATION table columns as attributes)
2. Team (NOMINATION + TEAM_NOM tables)
3. Idea (NOMINATION + IDEA_NOM tables)
4. Success (NOMINATION + SUCCESS_NOM tables)

So what I've done is use a discriminator (and inheritance) to establish their entities. For example:

Here's Entity Nomination:

```
  @Entity(name = "Nomination")
  @Table(name = "NOMINATION")
  @DiscriminatorColumn(name="CATEGORY_CODE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 1)
  @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)

  public abstract class Nomination extends AuditableEntity {
```

And here's how I'm coding Team, Idea and Success Entities:

```
  @Entity(name = "TeamNom")
  @Table(name = "TEAM_NOM")
  @DiscriminatorValue("T")
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "NOM_ID")

  public class TeamNom extends Nomination {
```

Now for Coworker I did the following:

```
  @Entity(name = "CoworkerNom")
  @DiscriminatorValue("C")
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "NOM_ID")

  public class CoworkerNom extends Nomination {
```

As you can see I have a big problem. Hibernate is looking for a table called "CoworkerNom", but I don't have any in our DB. I have tried putting in "Nomination" as table because I was out of ideas, but logically it gives me a circularity dependency error.

**So how do I approach this entity which has no table and no attributes?** The other Entities are working fine obviously.

Comment: It looks to me like you are mixing in domain classes into your dao classes.  CoworkerNom is not a table so why try to map it?  There may be a way to do what you want but I'm not sure.  You could let Nomination be a concrete class and create a database view name CoworkerNom that just selects * from Nomination and then map that as you have above changing the entity name to the view's name.

Comment: I've debated this, also considering just making a table called Coworker and dumping only the Ids on it. It is a interesting solution but I'd rather approach this via Hibernate. Either way thanks for the reply and I will consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hibernate you are going to have to create a table with the attributes for each subclass of Nomination, so you are going to have in practice this table only populated with ID's... The rationale behind this I think is so that you have the advantage that if you want to extend this subclass with specific properties in the future, you can do so without having much your annotations or schema changing.